# R: Non-conformable arguments, error when optimise a custom function

Tags: r

I wrote following function

```
costFunc=function(par,dat){
    state=sapply(mySamp,stateofMC,windDat=windDat)
    sum=0
    for(i in 1:3){
        state_loc=which(state==i)
        state_dat=dat[state_loc,,drop=F]     # m x 4 matrix
        state_coef=rbind(-par,1)[,i,drop=F]  # 4 x 1 matrix
        state_prod=state_dat %*% state_coef  # m x 1 matrix
        sum = sum + colSums(abs(state_prod))
    }
    return(sum)
}
```

It worked when I plugged in some values; but failed when I tried to optimise it, providing following error message:

```
forecstCoef=optim(par=tranProb,costFunc,gr=NULL, dat=dat, 
            method="Nelder-Mead")$par

Error in state_dat %*% state_coef : 
non-conformable arguments
```

I checked the class of state_dat and state_coef, they both output matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow it seems the error occurs in the line:
    `state_coef=rbind(-par,1)[,i,drop=F]`
It treats `par` as a vector instead of a matrix, desipte the initial value in the `optim` is a matrix. It works with following modification:

```
state_coef=rbind(-matrix(par,nrow=3),1)[,i,drop=F]
```